# Understanding AppArmor log messages

Tags: libreoffice, log, apparmor

I'm trying to understand different log messages in /var/log/kern.log that started appearing a few days ago. I'm new to AppArmor, I've read man pages and I understand the concepts, I've searched on the internet, however I haven't found answers to my questions so your help would be greatly appreciated :)

First, I have a lot of messages coming from LibreOffice (oosplash and soffice.bin), when I start a LibreOffice app, like :

```
May 31 20:17:31 computer kernel: [323998.794468] audit: type=1400 audit(1590949051.499:526): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="connect" profile="libreoffice-oopslash" name="/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_ebf4c14b10ff5047a7c52cb16b89cb45" pid=21191 comm="oosplash" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
May 31 20:17:31 computer kernel: [323998.794473] audit: type=1400 audit(1590949051.499:527): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" profile="libreoffice-oopslash" name="/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_ebf4c14b10ff5047a7c52cb16b89cb45" pid=21191 comm="oosplash" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

or

```
Jun  2 12:52:06 computer kernel: [ 4343.092338] audit: type=1400 audit(1591095126.931:125): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/user/.thunderbird/profiles.ini" pid=6459 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

A general question about understanding this log file - libreoffice is in complain mode, so are the above messages just an information ? Should I look at apparmor="ALLOWED" or denied_mask="r" (in order to know what's going on) ?

Although I've found that LibreOffice-AppArmor issues are not uncommon, like people not being able to access files outside of their HOME folders (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1751005) and hence disabling the profile completely or 
I guess I could run aa_genprof and define current LibreOffice behavior as normal, but I'd still like to know what's going on. For exemple, what does it mean operation="connect" ? Or why soffice.bin opens /home/user/.thunderbird/profiles.ini (or similar seemingly unrelated files) ? I find these things weird, I don't even use thunderbird...

Other log messages appear on system startup and include :

```
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [    0.156884] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [    0.156893] audit: type=2000 audit(1591099123.044:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.515084] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.471:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="klogd" pid=1009 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.570111] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.527:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="gst_plugin_scanner" pid=1010 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.627380] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.583:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ping" pid=1012 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.668657] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.627:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="syslogd" pid=1014 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.702750] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.659:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="syslog-ng" pid=1017 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.782911] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.739:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1011 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.783708] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.739:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1011 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.784281] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.739:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=1011 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.784960] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.743:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1011 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 13:59:01 computer kernel: [   14.819066] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099138.775:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/irssi" pid=1025 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun  2 14:03:53 computer kernel: [  309.414167] kauditd_printk_skb: 89 callbacks suppressed
Jun  2 14:03:53 computer kernel: [  309.414168] audit: type=1400 audit(1591099433.199:101): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon" pid=4090 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I see it's a STATUS message but I'm still confused by profile="unconfined" since I couldn't find this profile in /etc/apparmor.d. What is apparmor_parser loading ? Is this dangerous and should I confine these applications ?

I'm sorry if my question is a bit broad, a lot of stuff happens at the same time

Comment: Might this help explain things? https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-the-apparmor-mode-for-a-service-in-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Hello User, and thanks for your reply. The article you provided shows a few very basic apparmor commands and my question is actually about understanding log file and troubleshooting the issue, not the usage. If I don't understand what the issue is, I can't type the commands and write profiles... Thanks anyway :)